# Finding where a complex function is differentiable and holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

My function is $f(z)$ = $4$ Re($z$)Im($z$) - $i$($\overline{z}$)$^2$

I simplified my function to be in the form $u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ then applied the Cauchy Riemann eq's and determined that the function is differentiable on the line $y = -x$ and not holomorphic anywhere since the line has no width.  Is this right?

Also is there a way to express the derivative of the function in terms of $z$ and not just partials with respect to  $x$ and $y$ ?  My notes from class don't have anything on that.

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: This applies to your other questions too - please accept answers on those that you feel have answered your question to remove them from the unanswered queue!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question, if you know the derivative at a point as a $2 \times 2$ Jacobian matrix of partials, and if you also know from the Cauchy Riemann equations that $f(z)$ is differentiable as a function of $z$ at that point, then that Jacobian matrix must have the form $$\begin{pmatrix} r \cos(\theta) & r \sin(\theta) \\ -r \sin(\theta) & r \cos(\theta) \end{pmatrix}$$ for some $r \ge 0$ and some $\theta$, and therefore you can write $f'(z)$ as the complex number $$f'(z) = r \cos(\theta) + r \sin(\theta) \, i$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=a+ib$ with real $a,b.$ Then $f(z)=4 a b-i (a-ib)^2=$ $4 ab-i a^2+2 i^2 a b-i^3 b^2=$ $=4 a b-i a^2-2 a b+i b^2=$ $2 a b-i a^2+ i b^2 =$ $(-i)(a^2+2 a b i-b^2)=$ $-i z^2.$

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

> I simplified my function to be in the form $u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ then applied the Cauchy Riemann eq's and determined that the function is differentiable on the line $y = -x$ and not holomorphic anywhere since the line has no width.  Is this right?

This is correct since we require $\mathbb{C}$-differentiability on **open** subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. The line $y = -x$ contains no open disks/balls of any radius, so $f$ is not holomorphic anywhere.